# how to fix this code to meet the requirements?

Tags: java, object, oop, methods

**My code**

main:

```java
public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        bank acc = new bank();

        acc.acc1 = 1123.979;
        acc.acc2 = 543.758;

        System.out.println("account1 balance: " + "$" + acc.acc1);
        System.out.println("account2 balance: " + "$" + acc.acc2);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter amount for account1: ");
        acc.WAmount1 = input.nextInt();;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Subtracting " + acc.WA1 + " from account1 balance");
        acc.debit();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter amount for account2: ");
        acc.WAmount2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Subtracting " + acc.WA2 + " from account2 balance");

        acc.Debit();
    }
}
```

I tested the code and it works perfectly fine. The problem is with the code, I think the instruction said that I can only provide 1 method in the `Account` class which is the **wdraw**.

Answer (score 1):

One Account class should only contain one amount field. If you have several accounts, you create new instances of the same class, so each instance holds the information for one account and one account only.

The withdrawal method should take the amount to withdraw as a parameter, since the amount to withdraw is not a inherent part of the account but a temporary value linked to one withdrawal operation

So something like

```
public class Account {
  double amount;

  public void withdraw(double withdrawal){
     if (amount - withdrawal< 0){
        System.out.println("the debit amount exceeded the account balance");
     } else { 
         amount-=withdrawal;
     }
     System.out.println("account balance: $" + amount);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to decrement amount by withdrawal if it's possible (enough funds).

And then you can instantiate multiple accounts:

```
Account account1=new Account();
// set amount and do withdrawals on account1

Account account2=new Account();
// set amount and do withdrawals on account2
```

Comment: JP Moresmau can I ask for a favor if you can finish the method in the account class? I have trouble analyzing it.

Comment: Added very basic implementation, adapt to your needs

Comment: JP Morescau did you try the code sir? because when I put the implementation that you provided the output is wrong. Can you please complete it for me cause I really can't understand what the code is  lacking. I

Comment: it only shows the ouput for account 1. Do I need another implementation? I still can't solve it